# Data Recovery gave me more data than I had

Tags: windows-10, partitioning, data-recovery, mbr, partition-recovery

I have a drive with a MBR partition table, and a 2TB NTFS partition.

I performed data recovery on the 2TB partition using Wondershare Recoverit, and when the program finishes, you can recover your files using a standard file tree, for example `C\Users\Bob\Pictures\Cat.jpg` or it allows you to recover the files by themselves, with no folders. When I ONLY selected the file tree files, it adds up to 3TB of files.

How can it give me 3TB of files from a 2TB partition? Thank you.

Comment: That is a question which you should ask Wondershare, especially since you've paid big money for it.

Comment: It's probably recovering deleted files which have since been overwritten by something else, resulting in data duplication - sectors which map to multiple deleted files at once

Comment: I looked at more of the recovered files, and discovered that there are duplicates, but it gets weirder. So a large amount of the files that I recovered have a "  _1   " append on them. The original file will be there, but it usually cannot be opened, it is a dead file, and the duplicate name has a  "  _1  " on the end of it, and it can always be opened:    ExampleFile  (dead original name)   ExampleFile_1   (duplicate works perfectly). The pattern is the same for any type of file, photo, video, audio, other.

Comment: It gets weirder than that, while most of the original file names are dead files that do not open, regardless of their file extension type, there are a few of the original file names that do open, but they are not what they say they are. Example: an original file would be Beatles.mp3  file, but when you open it, it could be britney spears. At first I thought maybe the original file was mislabeled, but I saw this patten in many places, although it was still a minority of the origina filenames. Most of the original filenames are unopenable files. Why does Recoverit do this?

Comment: Every data recovery I've done has recovered more data than was on the drive. Understanding what is going on, how data recovery works, will help you understand what's going on here. It's completely normal. But to put it briefly, data recovery scans a drive and makes a lot of guesses about the files it finds. Depending on many factors it will have a better or worse ability to recover and recreate the files it finds, but because of those guesses it WILL find more data than was on the drive when you scanned it.